# How to find a user's record via CloudKit Dashboard

Tags: cloudkit

As far as I can tell, Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/managing_icloud_containers_with_cloudkit_dashboard/handling_an_icloud_container_s_data) on using the CloudKit Dashboard doesn't explain how to look up specific users' records.

So, let's say one of my users wants me to delete their iCloud data from my app's public database.

**What's the best way to find that particular record in the CloudKit Dashboard?**

There's the `createdBy` system field -- but how do I connect that to a user? There's also a `recordName` system field that holds an ID of some kind.

Please advise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the created/modified field on a record, you'll see below it a long string that is a unique `recordName` (it starts with a `_`) that corresponds to a user in the `Users` table in your container.

[image]

You can query the `Public` database in the CloudKit Dashboard by that `User` `recordName`. You can then select those records and delete them.

[image]

If it's a lot of records, it would probably be more efficient to write a little Swift code to fetch the `recordID`s with a `CKQuery` that searches the created or modified field. Once you fetch those `recordID`s, you can submit them with a `CKModifyRecordsOperation` to delete them.

One final thing. You will probably need to have some way of showing the user their `User` `recordName` so that they can send it to you to request a deletion of their data. If you haven't associated any other data with the `Users` record then you won't be able to tell who is who.